# Objective-c Naming conventions for Methods

Tags: objective-c

I have a class that has the following properties:

- Name
- Email
- Username

I want to convert these properties to a dictionary. How can I properly name the method that does that to adhere to Apple's conventions?

I was thinking of:

```
- (NSDictionary *) convertToDictionary {}
```

Comment: what is your class called?

Comment: Also see Apple's [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa: Naming Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just `-dictionaryRepresentation`, to convey the notion that you can get the data stored in the object in dictionary form? So you'd say:

```
NSDictionary *personDict = [person dictionaryRepresentation];
```

Another reasonable choice would be `-properties`, leaving the return type out of the name:

```
NSDictionary *personDict = [person properties];
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider that to go from an `NSString` to an `NSData` you do:

```
NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Similarly you could just do:

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionary;
```

since you have no parameters. Or consider that to go from `NSData` to `NSString` you do:

```
[[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:encoding] autorelease]
```

The class method, if there was one, would look like:

```
[NSString stringWithData:data encoding:encoding]
```

so you could make it a category on `NSDictionary`. Say your class is called `Account`:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithAccount:(Account *)account;
```

Depends on what you think looks better:

```
Account *account = ...;

[account dictionary];
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithAccount:account];
```

Comment: He has a class and an instance. Why should he want to make it a class method (+dictionaryWithAccount:)? This makes little sense.

Comment: @ChristianKienle: you are correct, edited.